# Help DataBinding to Checkbox in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have a CheckBox in a ListBox.  I set the ListBox ItemsSource to a List of Agency.  Agency has a property

```
public class Agency 
{ 
  public bool isSelected { get; set;} 
}
```

```xml
<ListBox> <!-- ItemsSource set in codebehind to List<Agency> -->
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=isSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</ListBox>
```

I have a function to check all the checkboxes

```
//SelectAll button

    private void SelectAll_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      List<Agency> list = this.AgencySubListBox.ItemsSource as List<Agency>;
      for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
      {
        Agency d = list[i];
        d.isSelected = true;
      }
    }
```

When I hit the select all button I expect the checkboxes to all be checked.  But nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) for your Agency-class.
Then in your isSelected-Property, call PropertyChanged if the value of the property has been changed. [Auto-properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) as you used in your example do not support INotifiyPropertyChanged, therefore you can not use them for your purpose.
If you work with .net, I would also recommend to start the property names with upper case. This is the widely accepted standard.

Answer (score 1):

You should make your model implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx), and implement it

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to tell the UI that the your checkbox binding has been invalidated, and needs rechecking.  Therefore, implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx) on your `Agency` type.